# cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type int in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
func sortArrayBasedOnStartTime(_ array: NSArray) -> NSArray
{
  for eventDict in array
  {
       let startHourOfThisEvent : String = self.getStartHour((eventDict as! NSArray)["eventStartTime"] as! String)

       if(hourTemp as! String == startHourOfThisEvent)
       {
            arrSpecificHour.add(eventDict as! NSDictionary)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you receive the error exactly? Upon adding an item to arrSpecificHour?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem

```
(eventDict as! NSArray)["eventStartTime"]
```

You are converting a dictionary to an array, which obviously can't be accessed by string, arrays can be accessed only by integers.